# WordPress error: Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable

Tags: aws, wordpress

So I have just taken over managing a client's website and I am running into the error in the title whenever I try to update WordPress or install/update plugins.

So far I have tried creating a new `temp` folder and updating `WP_TEMP_DIR` in `wp-config.php` with the directory, changing the permissions of the temp folder to 755, and changing the permissions of wp-content, the plugins folder, and even the individual plugin folders to 755. Nothing has worked.

The website is hosted with AWS Lightsail, which I am not too familiar with, so I don't know if I am changing the correct folders. I have been editing in this directory via SSH: `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`